# Check if product image is base image?

Tags: magento

I got all images of a product by

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItems();
```

Here is the content of one item:

```
<i>protected</i> '_data' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=11)</i>
      'value_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'204'</font> <i>(length=3)</i>
      'file' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'/m/a/magento-red-furniture-set.jpg'</font> <i>(length=34)</i>
      'label' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'test label'</font> <i>(length=10)</i>
      'position' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'disabled' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'label_default' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'test label'</font> <i>(length=10)</i>
      'position_default' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'disabled_default' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'url' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'http://work.my/m1702/media/catalog/product/m/a/magento-red-furniture-set.jpg'</font> <i>(length=76)</i>
      'id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'204'</font> <i>(length=3)</i>
      'path' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'/var/www/m1702/media/catalog/product/m/a/magento-red-furniture-set.jpg'</font> <i>(length=70)</i>
```

How can I check in code if this image item is base image (or small image, thumbnail)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this.

```
if ($item->getFile() == $product->getImage()){
    //then it's image
}

if ($item->getFile() == $product->getSmallImage()){
    //then it's small image
}

if ($item->getFile() == $product->getThumbnail()){
    //then it's thumbnail
}
```

Keep in mind that it can be all 3 of them.

Comment: Your solution is simple and great, except one thing - if product was not loaded it will not work (but my example has load, by the way). I added such check and all works fine: $item->getFile() == Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($prod->getId(), 'image', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()); Thanks!